# How to connect magento2 to RabbittMQ on AWS

Tags: magento2, aws, rabbit-mq

I have two Ec2 instances in AWS, on one instance I have installed Magento 2 and on another ec2 instance, I have installed RabbitMQ. How can I connect Magento 2 with RabbitMQ?

I have given public IP of Ec2 where RabbitMQ is installed, and port 5672.

But I'm not able to connect. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have setup a user with password and a host on the rabbitmq server?
You can check with

```
rabbitmqctl list_users
```

If there is no user, create one:

```
rabbitmqctl add_user magento "magento"
```

Do you have added a host?
You can check with:

```
rabbitmqctl list_vhosts
```

If not, create one:

```
rabbitmqctl add_vhost magento
```

Then you need to connect user and host (e.g.)

```
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p 'magento' "magento" ".*" ".*" ".*"
```

The env.php in Magento should look like

```
'queue' => [
        'amqp' => [
            'host' => '__HOST__',
            'port' => '__PORT__',
            'user' => 'magento',
            'password' => 'magento',
            'virtualhost' => 'magento'
        ],
        'consumers_wait_for_messages' => 0
    ],
```

Sources:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/prod/config-reference-envphp.html
https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html

Comment: I tried with it but no luck